# Infinispan Hotrod remote server exception

Tags: distributed-caching, infinispan

I am trying to use Infinispan remote cache on the remote server. I am using 
Java application to connect to the server and store objects in the memory.

When I ran this application for the local hotrod server using loopback address
(127.0.0.1) it works. However, when I try to use it for remote server it fails.

Here is the code snippet:

import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCache;
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager;

```
public class HotRodRemoteClient {

     public void start() {
         RemoteCacheManager manager = new RemoteCacheManager("10.100.9.28");
         RemoteCache<Integer, Ticket> cache = manager.getCache();
      }
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
ISPN004017: Could not fetch transport
org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.TransportException:: Could not connect to server: /10.100.9.28:11222
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.<init>(TcpTransport.java:90)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.tcp.TransportObjectFactory.makeObject(TransportObjectFactory.java:57)
     at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory.borrowTransportFromPool(TcpTransportFactory.java:254)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory.getTransport(TcpTransportFactory.java:145)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.operations.FaultTolerantPingOperation.getTransport(FaultTolerantPingOperation.java:44)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.operations.RetryOnFailureOperation.execute(RetryOnFailureOperation.java:67)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.RemoteCacheImpl.ping(RemoteCacheImpl.java:432)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.ping(RemoteCacheManager.java:538)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.createRemoteCache(RemoteCacheManager.java:520)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.getCache(RemoteCacheManager.java:452)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.getCache(RemoteCacheManager.java:447)
     at com.packtpub.infinispan.chapter2.HotRodRemoteClient.start(HotRodRemoteClient.java:17)
     at com.packtpub.infinispan.chapter2.HotRodRemoteClient.main(HotRodRemoteClient.java:65)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
     at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:100)
     at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.<init>(TcpTransport.java:81)

             ... 13 more
```

I can ping the server 10.100.9.28:

```
shell> ping 10.100.9.28

PING 10.100.9.28 (10.100.9.28): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.100.9.28: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.261 ms
64 bytes from 10.100.9.28: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.184 ms
64 bytes from 10.100.9.28: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.290 ms
64 bytes from 10.100.9.28: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.285 ms
```

I use Infinispan 5.1.6, Maven 3.04, JDK6.33.

My hotrod server runs on Centos 5.5, but Java application is on Mac 10.7

Firewalls on both machines are disabled.

I suspect this is configuration problem. What should I change to make it to work?

Thank you,

Jacob Nikom

Comment: Could you run "netstat -apn --ip" on the server machine and look for the bindings on port 11222?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the port in constructor:

```
RemoteCacheManager manager = new RemoteCacheManager("10.100.9.28", port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Review in the configuration file standalone.xml than the socket binding for the hotrod has no interface or one that applies.
Default standalone.xml:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="hotrod" interface="management" port="11222"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="memcached" interface="management" port="11211"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Try changing

```
 <socket-binding name="memcached" interface="management" port="11211"/>
```

for

```
 <socket-binding name="memcached" port="11211"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Properties props = new Properties();
>
> props.put("infinispan.client.hotrod.server_list", "127.0.0.1:11222");
>
> RemoteCacheManager manager = new RemoteCacheManager(props);
>
> RemoteCache defaultCache = manager.getCache();

cited from: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Data_Grid/6.1/html/Getting_Started_Guide/Create_a_New_RemoteCacheManager.html

Hope this helps!